# iOS crashing when switching views

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Everything was working fine, then I deleted a view controller, replaced it with a TableView, made sure everything was renamed, built it, and ran it, once I click the button to switch to the table view, I get this http://prntscr.com/3r9uc7

Here's my code

```
NSLog( @"Logged In!" );
    availCourses *courses =
    [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"availCourses"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:courses animated:YES];
```

What I think might be the issue is I'm using instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier and pushViewController when it's a TableView controller. I just don't know how to switch!

Comment: Set an [exception breakpoint](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17802723/74815) and see why.

Comment: Please update the error log in you console- stack trace

Comment: TableViewController or TableView...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using segue on table cell selection with push action, you no need to `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` and push it manually.

Otherwise check table view controller `identity` — `Storyboard ID` and checked `Restoration ID` (this fields must be equal to `availCourses`)